# In data.table, performing an operation within one table, performs the same operation in another table as if they are linked

Tags: r, data.table

When I run the following code using the package 'data.table' it appears that `dt` and `dt1` are *linked*. Both of the tables now have the new `Calc` variable in it even though I only defined it in `dt1`.. What is going on here please?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Var1 = c(1,2,3), Var2 = c(4,5,6))
dt1 <- dt
dt1[, Calc := Var1 + Var2]
```

Comment: Use `dt1 <- copy(dt)`

Comment: Thanks, so the other command links the tables?

Comment: with `data.table`, set operations as well as `:=` use reference. So, if the newly created object is not copied, it gets modified

Comment: It might be useful to know that this is really a normal behavior for *most* programming languages. Usually, this is referred to as a shallow copy. A deep copy ensures the two objects aren't linked. In R, though, it's normally always a deep copy.

Comment: @Kat in R it is a normally shallow copy, deep copy is made later on only in case of altering the shallow copied object. It is called copy-on-write.

Comment: @billybob196, this is by design in `data.table`'s referential semantics. If you want `dt` and `dt1` to be completely separate objects, then as akrun suggested, use `dt1 <- copy(dt)`.